# Gridview null values for datetime in database results Object Can Not be cast from DBNULL to other types error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datetime, gridview, dbnull

I am using the gridview control which is connected to my database with an sqldatasource. I can do updates and deletes directly from this gridview.

When I edit a date field and remove the content, instead of writing null to database, it changes the value in database to 1900-01-01, and if I write manually null to the database, and use the edit button of gridview on that row for some other cell, below is the error.

> Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Answer (score 0):

First Check Is the Database column null-able?

You haven't mentioned which version of asp.net framework you are using.

For .net framework >= 3.5, you can use the nullable datatypes i.e. the binding should be with a datetime? field instead of datetime. The error you have mentioned is due the fact that you are trying to bind a null value to a variable of the type, datetime. Use dateime? and your error **"Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types"** will be resolved. Or you can do the following in the itemdatabound event:

```
yourTextBox.value = string.empty
if(((DataRow)e.Item.DataItem)["YourDateField"] != dbnull.value)
{
   yourTextBox.value = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["YourDateField"] .toString();
}
```

You haven't mentioned what you are doing for databinding/datasaving. In the data-saving code do the following:

```
datetime? saveDate = null;
if(!string.isnullorempty( yourTextBox.value))
    {
     saveDate = converto.datetime(  yourTextBox.value);


     }

//Use the saveDate for the saving.
```